# Handlebars: How to pass in parameter for nested variables in partials?

Tags: handlebars.js

I've been searching everywhere but haven't been able to find an answer (or maybe handlebars doesn't allow this yet).

For partials I know you can do this

```
{{> partial parameter=blue}}
```

But how do I go about doing something like this?

```
{{> partial parameter.parameter2=blue}}
```

My partial would look something like this:

```
class="{{#if parameter.parameter2}}{{parameter.parameter2}}{{/if}}"
```

I've been searching everywhere but couldn't come up with an answer

Comment: Not sure to understand the question : do you need to pass 2 parameters or use parameter2 property from parameter  or something else ? If you want to pass 2 parameters @2C-B seems to have your solution, otherwise explain your question by giving an example of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second parameter in like this:

```
{{> partial parameter=blue parameter2=red}}
```

Inside the partial you can then add your conditional logic to deal with an absent parameter2.